# Streaming on demand videos to android devices without RTP/RTSP server - NOT live

Tags: android, ios, html, video

I need to be able to stream or view a video on Android devices. The files are at a remote location and the stream must be on demand. It does not have to be a "stream" but I need to be able to allow the user to watch the video somehow.

Using the HTML5 `<video>` element is not going to help since it has a limited support for file types and there are some subtitles errors and bugs, and with the current library of videos I have converting them all is not even close to doable.

After searching the internet for 2 weeks I found 2 ways of doing this:
1. Use an RTP server
2. Parse the file location to an already existing player app (MX player / iOS player / Video player...etc)

Using an RTP server is not possible since their fees are prohibitely expensive. It is also a very hard subject to search on the internet

Using an internal app hasn't been easy to accomplish either, I would need to set an intent many other things in the app but the apps are 3rd party apps that i want to use.

---

I am stuck and I have no clue what to do here. I prefer something like the HTML5 `<video>` tag which does not need any transcoding, simply set the file's location content to the client and the client deals with the viewing. Of course flash is out of the picture here.

I found something similar to what I want to do. If you have an android phone you can check this:
http://www.animeboy.tv/mobile/streaming/the-prince-of-tennis/the-prince-of-tennis-episode-178.html
by clicking the link(and waiting for 10 seconds) the phone asks you what app you wish to use to open it, by specifying any player app it plays it using that player.
The problem is how can i tell the android /iOS system to do that? there is nothing on that on the internet!
I managed to make the system ask the user to select a program by setting the link with an RTSP protocol (`<a href="rtsp://address/movie.mp4">Link</a>`) but it says there is an error playing this link (There is no RTSP streaming on anyway)

How can I tackle this problem? Is there something I have missed?

I am asking here after almost 2 weeks of searching, I just keep drawing blanks, I don't have any experience with multimedia handling and handling so programming something of my own for this is also out of the picture.

Comment: do you want to stream to a web page, or to a native app? if it's a web page then your content is either going to have to be in a format that `<video>` supports or you would need to use MediaSource to write your own extension (not trivial). Servers like Kaltura are very inexpensive. If it's a native app, as long as the app supports the protocol Android will handle the association for you

Comment: @Offbeatmammal either a webpage or a native app, I just need to give the user the capability to watch it online if he wishes. I'd also like to avoid RTP servers since the server is an old centrino powered laptop with 256mb RAM, upgrade is not possible at the moment, it's enough for supporting the web server

Comment: @Offbeatmammal isn't there a way to make a link to the file it self but make the android/ios tell the user to select an app?

Comment: in HTML5 you can add the `download` attribute to a link. You will need the server to send the right MIME type for the file so that the browser knows what app(s) to ask to handle it

Comment: @bakriawad is this solved?